# Java: Need to replace different string types on single line and then print to txt file

Tags: java, replace, io

I know this a beginner java questions, but I need to read a madlib file where the words that need to be replaced are in between <>, i.e. .  It then prompts the user for a word of the same type, and I almost have it done except for when there are "<"blah">" two on the same line on the same line.  I may just need an outsider's view to point out the obvious, but I can't get it.  And I know that an ArrayList would be perfect, but I can only use scanners, PrintStreams, and simple Arrays.  Here's what I have thus far for the method:

```
public static void readFilePrint(Scanner console, File fileIn) throws    
       FileNotFoundException {
  PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(new File("out1.txt"));
  Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(fileIn);   
  String line = "";
  String temp = "";
  String token = "";
  int count = 0;

  String toRep = "";
  boolean multiple = false;
while (fileScan.hasNextLine()) { 
  line = fileScan.nextLine();
  String tempo = line;
  Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);  
  while (lineScan.hasNext()) { 

     token = lineScan.next();

     if (token.charAt(0) =='<') {

        String type = toRep.substring(1, token.length() - 1);
        System.out.print("Please type a/an " + type + ":"); 
        //word to replace toRep (same as token)
        String word = console.next();

        line = line.replace(token, word);
        toRep = token.substring(0, token.length() - 1);   
        toRep = line.replace(token, word);         
        temp  =  toRep;
        count++;
        if (count >= 1) {
          toRep +=  " " + temp;
        }
      }
      count = 0;

   }   

}
```

This is the only method that I need help with, it writes perfectly.  I'm sorry about the jumble of variables; sometimes I create vars to test different ideas to solve the problem, comment the origs out and then forget.  I know I'm just having a brain fart, because there are so many better objects that can accomplish this task.  I haven't used hard-coded like this in a long time so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I can only use..." <-- why? Which entity restricts your tools?

Comment: can you tell me the utility of `toRep`, `temp` and `count`?

Comment: I don't really get your question, I'm afraid. I can tell you though it looks strange to me that you're trying to take the substring of `toRep` even though this is an empty string at the first call...